# images always getting smaller

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to add images to my web site homepage but when i added it always getting smaller how can i cover my page with images?

Here is my code:

```
const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        height: "90vh",
      }}
    >
      <img src={logo} alt="img" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tried object-fit:cover and width:100% but it doesnt work.

All images that i add seems like that:
[image]

Comment: Does adding a width to your div help?

Comment: @i tried width:100% but it doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `style={{display: 'block', height: '100%'}}` to the image and it will work.

By default `<img>` elements have `display: inline`. It doesn't matter how tall the parent is, it will try to adjust to the width of the parent which, in your case, is shrinked by the centering method.

Comment: Now it seems top left corner and it doesnt cover whole page. Are there any solution to cover whole page

Comment: Of course there is. Anything is possible. But... that's not clear from your question.

Comment: It looks to me like you have difficulties expressing what you want in technical terms. And that's OK. Would it be easier for you to draw how it's supposed to look like? Because at this point I think you actually want to use a `backgroundImage`, not an `<img>`.

Answer (score 0):

i think that

```
display: "flex",
justifyContent: "center",
alignItems: "center",
height: "90vh",
```

is breaking it, try to add width/height to your image